# ps1 to exe deployment of Powershell Script, Cannot find all the information required

Tags: powershell, installation

I'm trying to create a `.exe` file that will run a powershell script that I have to install various components of an application. I'm working on step 1 of 4 to get this entire application installed and want to get it into one package. Things are not going well with it. I am using Ps1 to Exe by f2ko. There is no documentation that I can find on the software, but it does what I want it to. The issue is in the packaged files and how it is run. I am running into a couple issues. The primary issue seems to be with `Start-Process`, When the `exe` is running I get an error that states

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run completely because the system cannot find all the information required.
At C:\Users\adminjp\AppData\Local\Temp\2605.tml\2606.tmp\2607.ps1:9 char:16
```

The remainder of the error is obscured by a status bar for the installer. The status bar runs, but the process does not. I initially had an issue with `ExecutionPolicy` but that is rectified by manually changing the value in order to run the script. I have been having multiple issues getting this script to run and am running out of articles online that I haven't read. Here is my powershell script:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Force remotesigned

$NETfile = "env:p2eincfilepath\1 - NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
$NETargs = "/q"
$SQLfile = "env:p2eincfilepath\setup.exe"
$SQLargs = "/ConfigurationFile=`".\ConfigurationFile_SQLExpress.ini`""

function Show-Progress ($file, $arguments, $component){
    $process = Start-Process $file $arguments -PassThru
    for($i = 0; $i -le 100; $i = ($i + 1) % 100)
    {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Installer" -PercentComplete $i -Status "Installing $component"
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
        if ($process.HasExited) {
            Write-Progress -Activity "Installer" -Completed
            break
        }
    }
}

Show-Progress $NETfile $NETargs ".NET 4.7.2"
Show-Progress $SQLfile $SQLargs "SQL Express"
```

The program that converts this script to an `exe` is what sets the extraction location and, to the best of my knowledge, I have no way to set that. Attached is a screenshot of their explanation of how to reference the embeded files:

[image]

I am using `env:p2eincfilepath` because that is the powershell method of accessing environment variables and the application appears to create or use an environment variable. Please let me know if there is any other information you might need. The Ps1 appears to work correctly if I run it directly from powershell and put the files in the root directory, calling them with `./` I would really like to keep this function in use since this is what gives me my status bar letting the user know what is being installed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have a `$` sign in front of the env variable for it to fill in. e.g.

```
$NETfile = "$env:p2eincfilepath\1 - NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
$NETargs = "/q"
$SQLfile = "$env:p2eincfilepath\setup.exe"
$SQLargs = "/ConfigurationFile=`".\ConfigurationFile_SQLExpress.ini`""
```